# Vue-router: Load named view without reloading current active view

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I use vuejs with vue-router 2.0. Now I need the following. If I click on settings, an overlay should appear above the current content and the content should not be reloaded/rendered again and the url should be updated.

**app/dashboard/appsettings** *-> content app is loaded and above the overlay with settings*

**app/album/appsettings** *-> content album is loaded and above the overlay with settings*

**app/album/gallery/appsettings** *-> content gallery is loaded and above the overlay with settings*

How can I do that?

I tried this one

```
// router.js
path: '/settings',
name: 'settings',
components: {
  default: Album,
  overlay: Settings
},
meta: { auth: true }


// app.vue
<router-link :to="{ name:'settings', path: '/settings/' }">settings</router-link>
<router-view></router-view>
<router-view name="overlay"></router-view>
```

But how can I set the default view dynamically and the path?

**updated routes**

At the moment my routes are very simple, only the **Photo** view should also open in the overlay

```
const routes = [
{
  path: '/',
  component: Signin,
  name: 'home',
  meta: { auth: false, layout: 'simple' }
},
{
  path: '/signin',
  component: Signin,
  name: 'signin',
  meta: { auth: false, layout: 'simple' }
},
{
  path: '/dashboard',
  component: Dashboard,
  name: 'dashboard',
  meta: { auth: true }
},
{
  path: '/album',
  name: 'album',
  component: Album,
  meta: { auth: true }
},
{
  path: '/category/:id',
  name: 'category',
  props: true,
  component: Category,
  meta: { auth: true }
},
{
  path: '/gallery/:id',
  name: 'gallery',
  props: true,
  component: Gallery,
  meta: { auth: true }
},
{
  // This view should also be opened later in the overlay, I think this must be a childview than
  path: '/photo/:id', 
  name: 'photo',
  props: true,
  component: Photo,
  meta: { auth: true }
},
{
  path: '/settings',
  name: 'settings',
  components: {
    default: Album,
    overlay: Settings
  },
  meta: { auth: true }
}
```

];

gregor

Comment: Can we see your full list of routes?

Comment: @CENT1PEDE I've updated my question with the routes

Comment: Try this, instead of associating the overlay with a child route, why not just use a dialog triggered to open when a certain url query params is present. Say `/settings/album/:imageId?openDialog=true` `:imageId` is the id of the image you want to show, and `?openDialog=true` will determined whether you want to show the image in a dialog or not. I don't know if the situation is the same with your example but, it should give you an idea. What's the overlay for anyway?

Comment: Hmm I would prever a solution with a clean url, later i also need routes like gallery/:id/upload, gallery/:id/edit. I will use this overlay for many things, the overlay is more like a huge sidepanel (that is related to the active content) that gets triggered in moste of the cases to manipulate the active view. But I thought i could also use this overlay/sidepanel to show things like settings/password reset and so on

Comment: If so you can `gallery/:id/:action` where action is edit, upload etc. Depending on the action you can manipulate the components to show.